# Is there any way or workaround to have a perforce client-side trigger?

Tags: triggers, perforce, phpcodesniffer

We don't have access to the server but we would like to run a code sniffer before submit the files to the depo. I know this is very simple having access to the server triggers but is there any possibility to have something like that in the client side? So if my script returns 1 it should cancel the submission operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Perforce Broker is a pretty nice tool for this: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4sag/11_broker.html

Comment: The perforce broker can run filter programs to accept or reject specific commands from specific users -- but can a filter program run on the client, or only on the server? Docs don't specify, which makes me think filters are server-side only.

Comment: I agree - the language in the docs (`The Perforce Broker is a server process`) indicates that this is still a server function, and not actually client-only.